# MySQL ORDER BY decimal value not working

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

The SQL query with `order by` clause is not working properly.

```
VALUES:
5.0000   
4.0000   
4.5000  
4.7500  
4.0000  
5.0000
```

Query:

```
SELECT  AVG(rating) as rating
FROM review
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY CAST(`rating` as signed) DESC
```

When I execute this query, the output is:

```
5.0000  
4.7500  
4.5000  
5.0000  
4.0000  
4.0000
```

My rating column is `int(10)`.

Comment: It is ordering by the original `rating` column, not by your `AVG`. Don't use the same name as an alias to not confuse things and MySQL is well known for allowing silly things like this (using non-aggregated column in aggregation) and not telling you that you're doing wrong things.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, actually an invalid ORDER BY/GROUP BY combination.

Comment: @jarlh query in question works as required if the cast is removed - I have no idea why,  any thoughts?

Comment: @P.Salmon, MySQL specific behavior...? (Perhaps removed in newer MySQL versions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to order by `AVG(rating)` not by `rating`

```
SELECT AVG(rating) as rating FROM review GROUP BY id ORDER BY AVG(rating) DESC
```

In your case, alias and column have the same name. In order to avoid confusion, you can do:

```
SELECT AVG(rating) as avgrating FROM review GROUP BY id ORDER BY avgrating DESC
```

Comment: Or even better, ORDER BY columnalias.

Comment: @Shihas, should be, but don't trust it. It's good programming practice to not re-use column names as column aliases.

Comment: @jarlh ok. will do so :)

Comment: @jarlh If I'm using a join query then it has some issue.

Comment: @Shihas, start a separate question for that issue! (You can have a link to this one, if you think it'll be needed.)

Comment: SELECT  AVG(rating), COUNT(review) review_count,`current_name`, `verify` FROM `search_result` LEFT JOIN `review` ON `search_result`.`id` = `review`.`reg_id` AND `review`.`active` = 0 WHERE ( ( FIND_IN_SET('India', location) !=0 ) ) AND ( `hire_work` =0 AND `search_result`.`active` =0 ) GROUP BY `id` ORDER BY AVG(rating) DESC

Comment: Can you please check this query?

Comment: @Shihas, As a new, separate question. Not a comment.